# How To select a specific Div from its Class with JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Let's say this is my html:

```
<div class="picture_holder_thumb">
<div class="picture"> <a href="…"><img></a></div>
<div class="captioning"><div class="title" display: none; ">TITLE</div></div>
</div>
```

This creates a visual Index of Thumbnails as can be seen here:

[www.cyrill-kuhlmann.de/index.php/projects](http://www.cyrill-kuhlmann.de/index.php/projects)

I have a JS that shows the title of each thumbnail according to the cursors position:

```
script type='text/javascript'>
var mouseX;
var mouseY;
$(document).mousemove( function(e) {
 mouseX = e.pageX; 
 mouseY = e.pageY;
 });  
 $(".picture_holder_thumb").mouseover(function(){
 $(".title").css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX}).fadeIn('slow');
 });

 $(".picture_holder_thumb").mouseout(function(){
 $(".title").fadeOut('slow');
 });
 </script>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.captioning .title {
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
    color: #FFF;
    display: none;

 }
```

And it works, but the problem is that it shows ALL Titles at once! How can I achieve that it only shows this ".title" that "lies in" the .picture_holder_thumb that I am hovering?

Is that possible? Unfortunately I can't change the classes in to ID's because of the CMS structure…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `this` as the `context` to the selector.

Try,

```
$(".title", this)
```

instead of

```
$(".title")
```

Full code would be,

```
 $(".picture_holder_thumb").mouseover(function(){
   $(".title", this).css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX}).fadeIn('slow');
 });

 $(".picture_holder_thumb").mouseout(function(){
   $(".title", this).fadeOut('slow');
 });
```

Comment: would be the best solution.

Comment: YES! Thank You! It works! But the .title does not really stick to the cursor (I want it like a tooltip). Do I have to manage this with CSS or in the JS Code?

Comment: @CyrillKuhlmann You can handle it via script.. Need to apply some adjustment based on some mathematical calculations..

Comment: Ok so I better ask it in a new question?

Comment: @CyrillKuhlmann Yeah, you are right.. If we continue discuss about that here, then that would pollute this post and that makes this post unusable to the future visitors..

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
$(".picture_holder_thumb").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).children(".title").css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX}).fadeIn('slow');
});
```